# Date format issue in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdateformatter

I am facing a a strange issue in date. i am getting varied results on the time format.
My code is

```
 formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mma"];
    NSDate  *currentdate=[formatter dateFromString:[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    NSLog(@"Current Date %@",currentdate);
```

My output in simulator and other device are

> Current Date 2013-11-13 11:55:00 +0000

But in one particular device(Iphone 5):the ouput i am recieving is

> Current Date 2013-11-13 11:57:00 am +0000

Please help me to solve this issue.Thanks

Comment: NSDate does not have a format. "format" the contents of an NSDate into an NSString of your preferred format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is displaying a different hour you may need to set the default timezone after setting the dateFormat (this happens only after ios7)

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

it seems that the default timezone is the one the device has, so if you no specify the default timezone you might get strange results. Prior to ios7 it was always GMT.

**update:**

if the `NSDate` is nil after the formatting you should probably use:

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

I had this issue with a Mexican iPhone, if you like your users to be happy with your app I strongly recommend always adding this code. I always use both code sniplets since IOS7

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your "Date time format" set in iPhone Default Setting (Setting -> General -> Date and Time).

if in this setting time format is set as 24 hr then u will get time in 24 hr format.

If it is set as 12 hr format then u will get 12 hr date time format.

I think in ur iPhone5 device date time setting is set as 12 Hr format

Comment: true, I run date formatter code in  ios7 and ios8 for following format 
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"]
according to format I should get 20/10/2015 09:30 pm this value but in iOS 7 m getting 20/10/2015 21:30 because in my system setting I set 24hr format for time so when I changed "date time" display setting